# Getting size of div before appending to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I'm doing an ajax call. The function called on success looks as follows:

```
function(data){
            $div.html(data);
            posX=window.mouseX+1;
            posY=window.mouseY+1;
            if(posY-$(document).scrollTop()+$div.height()>$(window).height()){
                posY-=$div.height();
            }
            $div.css('left',posX+'px');
            $div.css('top',posY+'px');
            $div.appendTo($('body'));
        }
```

The idea is: if the div positioned at mouse coordinates is not gonna fit the browser size, then I put it above the mouse pointer instead.
The problem is that $div.height() is returning 0 if I call it before appending it to the body. Is there a way to get the height other than appending first and moving after?

Comment: Have you tried putting the script at the end of the page (just before the body tag)?

Comment: What is `$div`? Where are you assigning that variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert it with display: none and use jQuery's width() and height() function.